# Soap Ui wrong JSON elements position after propert transfer

Tags: jquery, json, soap, groovy

I have problem with testing REST api. For example method request look like this:

[image: request]

As you see I need here id and password so I use groovy script to generate fake id and then I use property transfer.

But after property transfer JSON element position has change

[image: JSON element position]

Can somone tell me why it`s happen? Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: Why is this a problem? You should never rely on the order of the keys in a json object,because that order has no meaning.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Cause api which i'm testing is not the best:/ And it requires JSON keys in good order. Is it posible  to achive that?

Comment: JSON maps do not have order.  I would say you'd found a bug in the system you are testing...  How are you creating the JSON? Can you show the code?

Comment: @tim_yates No it,s not a bug.  Programmers said, api will work in this way for some period of time. So i have to write tests with json keys in order.

Comment: Putting aside the fact that they've written stupid code, and can't or won't fix it, the second question still stands; can you show your code you're using to generate the json?